# Isn't _ characters allowed in field name for a table?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

For e.g., there is a table with a field `_autoScope`.

When I am querying data with no filters or conditions (scan), I receive data, and, I can confirm that `_autoScope` is part of the data. Similarly, there is no issue "putting" an item in dynamodb either.

However, I tried this and it bombed:

```
$ aws dynamodb scan --table-name ModelDefinition --endpoint-url $ENDPOINT_URL --filter-expression '_autoScope = :val' --expression-attribute-values file://values.json

An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the Scan operation: Invalid FilterExpression: Syntax error; token: "_", near: "_autoScope"
```

And the docs don't say much about naming rules for field names either: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.NamingRulesDataTypes.html

Is there a workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should also use `ExpressionAttributeNames`:

```
aws dynamodb scan \
--table-name ModelDefinition \
--endpoint-url $ENDPOINT_URL \
--filter-expression '#nam = :val' \
--expression-attribute-values file://values.json \
--expression-attribute-names '{"#nam":"_autoScope"}'
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ExpressionAttributeNames.html